# Where should I exchange euros to rubles?

Tags: europe, money, russia, exchange

Where should I exchange euros to rubles once I arrive in Russia (Example: Moscow (at any of the three airports))? Is there a special place directly at/near the airport that takes care of this?

*Or*

Should I exchange euros to rubles while in home country (France).

It was mentioned on [this](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g298484-i718-k3575554-Where_is_the_best_place_to_change_roubles-Moscow_Central_Russia.html) site that:

> It's better to change USD or Euro in banks, it's more safer. At the
>   airport there`s not best rates.

Is that even true?

*Or*

Can my visa card withdraw rubbles at an ATM in Russia?

Comment: Not sure about the specific Rubles case, but in general, the best option is to withdraw from an ATM. Make sure however you check your bank's fees for withdrawals abroad, and how much currency exchange commission they charge over the interbank rate (usually around 3%). Also, some banks may need you to notify them you are abroad before allowing use of your card there, check with yours before leaving.

Comment: @jcaron alright, thanks for the comment. I'll check with my bank and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many exchange places, both in airports and in city proper. Technically and officially they all are bank branches, but often it consists of an exchange office only.

The airport exchange rates are not the best, though if you are not changing lots of money, probably the price difference will not be worth your time.

You can withdraw rubles from ATMs (and certainly you can pay by card, which is widely possible; in fact, you will not need much cash), unless your bank prohibits this; check with your bank in advance. Also find out the fees they could charge and the exchange rate they would apply; you may find the exchange rate quite decent. (Only beware that exchange rate changes daily or even hourly, so compare exchange rate of bank with current Moscow exchange rate.)

In fact, I don't know about French card in Russia, but in opposite situation (Russian card in Europe), I often find it to be the best rate to simply pay by card wherever possible, and withdraw from ATM if I need cash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check with my bank and see what they say.

Answer (score 3):

The cheapest and safest way would be to exchange in a Russian bank.
To find a best rate go to:
http://quote.rbc.ru/cash/#!/?sortf=BID&sortd=DESC&city=1&currency=2&summa=&period=60&pagerLimiter=70&pageNumber=1

Here you will find current rate for EUR/RUB in each branch, with info like address, phone and operating time. Rates can be updated hourly.
Right now you can even find rate +0.5% (to the Forex price)
So, no fees at all. You can't find such a good rates in France.

You can search for other currencies and you can search by a location (metro station) to find a close point to you.

Don't forget your passport with you.

> It's better to change USD or Euro in banks, it's more safer. At the
>   airport there`s not best rates.

That's true.

> Can my visa card withdraw rubbles at an ATM in Moscow?

Yes, it works. Check rates with you bank card issuer.
Usually 1-3% plus a minimum fee about 3 EUR, and maximum withdraw of equivalent 300/500/1000/3000 EUR.

P.S.: There is also another site, where you can also check current bank rates for currency exchange:
http://www.banki.ru/products/currency/cash/Moskva/#currency_sort=978

Answer (score 1):

Do it at a bank and not russian. There is Chase and some German banks in Moscow. Their rates are not so bad.

You might come across currency exchange places, but their rates are not so good as from international banks.

The worst you can do is exchange your money at the airport.

Answer (score -1):

This question was already asked some time ago.

It's probably best to exchange a small sum of money, just enough for a single day, at the airport. To find the best exchange rate near the place you'll be staying you may use the service mentioned in this answer (along with google translate). Or just ask someone in your hotel where the closest exchange is.

[What is the best way to change money in Moscow?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55428/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-money-in-moscow/55499#55499)